# Not sure exact problem. Returning from promise incorrectly or promise chaining incorrectly

Tags: node.js, promise, async-await, google-cloud-functions

I'm building a web **scraper** and sending multiple http requests from a cloud function using promises. The problem is I'm not sure where to include response.send().

My function getList() makes all the requests async/await style and I've tried putting the response.send in a .then block like so  ..

```
 getList().then((result)=>{

         response.send("got current logs " + result);

     }).catch(async (err) => {
     console.log(err);

})
```

I thought since getList() returns a promise it would execute and then when it's finished it would call response.send() and everything would work fine, but instead it never gets called. All the code writes successfully to the db, but then cloud function ends in a timeout.

I also tried using promise.all() like this, but I'm not sure I'm on the right track.

```
const requestPromise = getList()
Promise.all(requestPromise).then =>
response.send()
```

But that doesn't work either. Response.send() is never called. I've tried a lot of things I found online and on SO but haven't figured out my problem yet.

I actually thought that because getList() is all structured using async/await that I could just call it right after the function and it would work like this.

```
getList()
response.send()
```

But in that case getList() doesn't execute at all so I think res.send() is getting called before getList() has a chance to finish.

Obviously I'm still new at promise chaining and trying to learn what is going on. My error handling is not the best either, but here is the full code that I am working on.

If anyone could help it would be appreciated.

```
export const getCurrentLogs = functions.https.onRequest((req, response) => {
  const Promise = require("bluebird");

  const urlList = [];
  const ref = scheduleRef
    .get()

    .then(async snapshot => {
      //this loops through and gets the urls needed for the requests
      snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
        const scheduleGame = doc.data();
        const boxScoreUrl = scheduleGame.boxScoreURL;
        console.log("got url " + boxScoreUrl);
        urlList.push("https://" + boxScoreUrl + "/");
      });
      
      //here I'm calling getList() right after the loop should finish, but I've also tried it in its own .then block among other things. 
      getList()
        .then(result => {
          response.send("got current logs " + result);
        })
        .catch(async err => {
          console.log(err);
        });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log("Error getting url", err);
    });

  async function getList() {
    await Promise.map(urlList, (url, index, length) => {
      return new Promise(
        resolve => {
          const options = {
            uri: url,
            Connection: "keep-alive",
            transform: function(body) {
              return cheerio.load(body);
            }
          };

          console.log("got options for " + url + " / " + options);

          request(options)
            .then($ => {
              console.log("made request for " + url);

              const final = $(".center-content-container")
                .find(".final-text")
                .text()
                .trim();
              const time = $(".center-content-container")
                .find(".time")
                .text()
                .trim();

              console.log(final);
              console.log(time);

              $(".stats-rows")
                .find("tbody")
                .children("tr")
                .not(".total-row")
                .each(function(i, element) {
                  const playerPage = $(element)
                    .children("td")
                    .eq(0)
                    .find("a")
                    .attr("href");

                  const playerNameSplit = playerPage.split("/");
                  const playerDocRef = playerNameSplit[7];
                  console.log(playerDocRef);

                  return playersRef
                    .doc(playerDocRef)
                    .update({
                      currentLog: currentLog
                    })
                    .catch(error =>
                      console.error(
                        "Error adding document: ",
                        error + " : " + url
                      )
                    );
                });

              return;
            })
            .catch(async err => {
              console.log(err);
              return;
            });
        },
        {
          concurrency: 10
        }
      ).catch(async err => {
        console.log(err);
        return;
      });
    }).catch(async err => {
      console.log(err);
      return;
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: The indentation of almost all your code here is inconsistent and therefore difficult to read.  You might want to clean it up to make it easier for us.

Comment: Okay, will do..

Comment: This is a collection of several antipatterns. `new Promise` is promise construction antipattern, it's not needed. The use of `then` inside `async` defies the purpose of using `async`. Nested promises result in callback hell, they shouldn't be nested without a good reason. Promises aren't chained correctly, notably `getList()`.